# How to easily keep multiple Magento theme translations up-2-date?

Tags: localisation

Working with Magento Translations today I got very annoyed by the fact that I had to constantly repeat myself.

In our installation we currently have 4 languages:

```
en_US for English
nl_NL for Dutch
de_DE for German
es_ES for Spanish
```

For each of these languages I have to maintain separate `app/design/frontend/theme/package/locale/xx_XX/translate.csv` files, where the first column - the original language - is the same.

For instance, to translate / modify the original Magento word "Buy" into "Buy now" and the correct translation in these different languages I have to make the following edits in these four files:

```
locale/en_EN/translate.csv
"Buy", "Buy now"

locale/nl_NL/translate.csv
"Buy", "Nu kopen"

locale/de_DE/translate.csv
"Buy", "Jetzt Kaufen"

locale/es_ES/translate.csv
"Buy", "Comprar ahora"
```

Is there a smarter way to do this? Maybe working on just one theme_translate.csv that automatically splits into the correct locale/xx_XX/translate.csv's ??

```
Example theme_translate.csv file: 
"Buy","Buy now","Nu Kopen","Jetzt Kaufen","Comprar ahora"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes, there is a smarter way to do this! And it's so easy you start wondering why you didn't think of this 160*4 translated sentences earlier (...)

Using AWK or GNU AWK (gawk) you can quickly select the correct columns and output a new CSV file with just the first (original) column and the correct language column.

It works like this:

```
awk -F "," '{print $1 "," $3}' source.csv > output.csv
```

`-F ","` = use `","` as field separator. 
`{print $1 "," $3}` = output the first field `$1`, then `","` followed by the 3rd field `$3`. 
`source.csv > output.csv` = your source and your output files.

In my case I use these lines as a shell script in my build tool to generate the correct translation files:

```
awk -F "," '{print $1 "," $2}' ./src/locale/theme_translations.csv > ./dist/app/design/frontend/foundation/default/locale/en_EN/translate.csv
awk -F "," '{print $1 "," $3}' ./src/locale/theme_translations.csv > ./dist/app/design/frontend/foundation/default/locale/nl_NL/translate.csv 
awk -F "," '{print $1 "," $4}' ./src/locale/theme_translations.csv > ./dist/app/design/frontend/foundation/default/locale/de_DE/translate.csv
awk -F "," '{print $1 "," $5}' ./src/locale/theme_translations.csv > ./dist/app/design/frontend/foundation/default/locale/es_ES/translate.csv
```

**HOWEVER** If you have fields with commas in your translations (`"Order today, enjoy tomorrow"`) you'll be out of luck with regular awk. You'll need GNU awk as this version is able to use smarter regex patterns as field separator.

If you're on a mac like I am, installation of GNU awk is easy if you already have [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed on your mac: `brew install gawk` should do the trick.

instead of `-F ","` your field separator will look like `-vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"'` so the command looks like this:

```
gawk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{print $1 "," $3}' source.csv > output.csv
```

As my translations contained commas in the fields I ended up using gawk and it looks like this:

```
gawk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{print $1 "," $2}' ./src/locale/theme_translations.csv > ./dist/app/design/frontend/foundation/default/locale/en_EN/translate.csv
gawk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{print $1 "," $3}' ./src/locale/theme_translations.csv > ./dist/app/design/frontend/foundation/default/locale/nl_NL/translate.csv
gawk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{print $1 "," $4}' ./src/locale/theme_translations.csv > ./dist/app/design/frontend/foundation/default/locale/de_DE/translate.csv
gawk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{print $1 "," $5}' ./src/locale/theme_translations.csv > ./dist/app/design/frontend/foundation/default/locale/es_ES/translate.csv
```